# Invoke-DbaQuery Failure - The wait operation timed out

Tags: sql, powershell, dbatools

I try to run the following command:

```
$serverName = 'firjt6'
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance 'some site' -Database 'CM_IDC' -Query $query -SqlParameters @{SrvName = $serverName}
```

And I keep on getting the following error:

```
[Invoke-DbaQuery] Failure | The wait operation timed out
```

Does anyone know where should I add the command TimeOut property?

```
$serverName = 'firjt6'
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance 'some site' -Database 'CM_IDC' -Query $query -SqlParameters @{SrvName = $serverName}
```

Comment: Something like [`-QueryTimeout` parameter](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dbatools/0.9.419/Content/functions%5CInvoke-DbaQuery.ps1)?

Comment: yes, where should I add this parameter?

Comment: Add a _named_ parameter anywhere. In doubts, observe all possible syntax patterns using `get-command -Name Invoke-DbaQuery  -Syntax`